# Reading edge list data set in apache giraph?

Tags: giraph

I'm using [SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/index.html) dataset for social network analysis. SNAP uses simple edge list as a data format. How to read SNAP dataset in Apache Giraph?

Answer (score 1):

As per I know SNAP has various data formats depending upon which dataset you are looking at. If the dataset that you are looking at has the format : `sourceid destinationid` on each line then you might want to use IntNullTextEdgeInputFormat (it's in `giraph-core/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph/io/formats` ).

Also take a look at various predefined formats available in the same folder. If none of those fit for your dataset format then you can write your own input format class (it will be really simple if you start from the predefined formats and edit it as you need).

Answer (score 0):

use -eif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IntNullTextEdgeInputFormat

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SNAP uses Simple Edge List format for representing graph databases. You can use this [code](https://github.com/skymanaditya1/Apache-Giraph-Deployed-on-Apache-Hadoop/blob/master/EdgeListToJsonConversionFormatClassSorted.java) for converting it to a JSON format which is accepted by Apache Giraph.